# Help with evaluating pointwise and uniform convergence for two similar sequences of functions

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So i have thist two  sequences of functions:
$$f_{n}=n^6(\sqrt{nx+1}-\sqrt{nx})$$
$$g_{n}=n^{-\frac{1}{6}}(\sqrt{nx+1}-\sqrt{nx})$$

both of them are defined as: $(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

i want to investigate pointwise and uniform convergence for both sequence.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what happened to the right parentheses?

Comment: oh i messed up, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x\geq 0$, we have that $\displaystyle (\sqrt{nx+1}-\sqrt{nx})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{nx+1}+\sqrt{nx}}\in(0,1]$. Hence 
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} f_n(x)=\lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac{n^6}{\sqrt{nx+1}+\sqrt{nx}}=+\infty.$$
On the other hand
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} g_n(x)=\lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac{n^{-1/6}}{\sqrt{nx+1}+\sqrt{nx}}=0:=g(x).$$
In this case we have uniform convergence in $[0+\infty)$: as $n$ goes to $+\infty$,
$$\sup_{x\geq 0}|g_n(x)-g(x)|=n^{-1/6}\sup_{x\geq 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{nx+1}+\sqrt{nx}}=n^{-1/6}\sup_{t\geq 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{t+1}+\sqrt{t}}=n^{-1/6}\to 0.$$